# IUnable to use CKeditor search browser option in send frame

Tags: php, zend-framework, .htaccess, zend-route

I am using CK editor in my zend based web page.if i will open **browse server** option in CK Editor Image type . It gives following Error .

> Error : Invalid controller specified (phpdocs)

My .htaccess file has following configuration

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php/ [NC,L]
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Request Parameters:

```
array ('controller'      => 'phpdocs',
       'action'          => 'ptest',
       'public'          => 'js',
       'admin'           => 'ckfinder',
       'module'          => 'default',
       'type'            => 'Images',  
       'CKEditor'        => 'page_content', 
       'CKEditorFuncNum' => '2', 
       'langCode'        => 'en', )
```

Is it possible to change the url redirection. Please guide me how I rewrite the url.